# Inferring a Coder from the CoderRegistry failed: Unable to provide a Coder for com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I have a Dataflow job that runs fine when running locally using `DataFlowRunner` but when I try to run it using GCP's Composer/AirFlow it will give me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to return a default Coder for ConvertToYouTubeMetadata/ParDo(convertToTableRow$1)/ParMultiDo(convertToTableRow$1).output [PCollection]. Correct one of the following root causes:
    No Coder has been manually specified;  you may do so using .setCoder().
    Inferring a Coder from the CoderRegistry failed: Unable to provide a Coder for com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow.
    Building a Coder using a registered CoderProvider failed.
    See suppressed exceptions for detailed failures.
    Using the default output Coder from the producing PTransform failed: PTransform.getOutputCoder called.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:444)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.getCoder(PCollection.java:259)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.finishSpecifying(PCollection.java:107)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.finishSpecifyingInput(TransformHierarchy.java:190)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:536)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:491)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:299)
    at MainKt.runMetadataPipeline(main.kt:66)
    at MainKt.main(main.kt:34)
```

How is the execution different on Composer that's causing it to not work like it does when run locally?

I'm just using

`BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building my JAR using [`ShadowJar`](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) solved this problem for me. As Dataflow executes a JAR file using `DataFlowJavaOperator` I assumed that there was a problem in packaging the JAR. I can't remember where I read it on Github but someone mentioned using the Maven Shade plugin for this problem and this is Gradle's equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the shadowjar and still had this problem. What worked for me: Ive manually added the coder to the pipeline:

```
pipeline.getCoderRegistry().registerCoderForClass(TableRow.class, TableRowJsonCoder.of());
```